# Efficient algorithm for swapping dimensions for an N-dimensional matrix

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

I have data stored in N-dimensional matrixes (i.e. Arrays nested N layers deep). Is there a good standard solution - other than brute force - to the following two problems

1. I want to swap 2 dimensions for each other e.g. a 6 x **5** x **4** x 3 matrix will become a 6 x 4 x 5 x 3 matrix
2. I want to raise a dimension to being the 0th dimension, or lower it to be the Nth e.g. 6 x 5 x **4** x 3 x 2 goes to 4 x 6 x 5 x 3 x 2 or 6 x 5 x 3 x 4 x 2

I'm writing in JavaScript so a solution involving recursive functional programming would seem like a good route to take, but I'm struggling to think of a way to avoid the process getting overly complex and inefficient.

Comment: Isn't the answer going to depend on how the data is stored, i.e., how the matrix is represented?  What representation are you using?  Is it a dense matrix or a sparse matrix?  Is it an array where rows are stored consecutively?  An array of pointers to lower-dimensional matrices?  Something else?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation

Comment: Most often it'll be a very dense matrix. Not sure I understand what you mean by the other questions exactly - the link you provide doesn't give much further detail. Is `Arrays nested N layers deep` not clear enough?

Comment: Ultimately, memory is a linear (single-dimensional) structure.  There are many ways that matrices can be stored in memory.  This requires mapping the multi-dimensional matrix/array into a single-dimensional form.  The exact mapping / representation of the data will affect what kinds of operations are efficient.  For instance, accessing two bytes in the same cache line or page is more efficient than accessing two bytes that are far apart.  In practice, these factors play a huge role in the efficiency of matrix operations.  (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)